# xoj (Xournal) files handled as gzip despite presence of correct MIME type

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, mime-type, file-association, gzip

So I had to uninstall the [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8) [version](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8/precise/main/base/xournal) of [Xournal](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xournal/) and build from [source](http://sourceforge.net/code-snapshots/git/x/xo/xournal/code.git/xournal-code-6d4c59eb9bd2b50c661701a6c5b5fbcfc617eb17.zip) (with a [modification](https://sourceforge.net/p/xournal/bugs/112/?limit=10&page=1#000f)).  And now .xoj files open automatically with KDE's archive manager Ark, and are identified as being of type "Gzip archive" when one selects Properties from the right-click menu in Dolphin:
[image: xoj properties from Dolphin]
(Before, .xoj files opened with Xournal and were correctly identified.) This state of affairs persists despite all of the following:

1) Copied these files that come with the source package:
 - `xournal.xml` into /usr/share/mime/packages/
 - `xournal.desktop` into /usr/share/applications/
 - `x-xoj.desktop` into /usr/share/mimelnk/application/

2) added the line
   `application/x-xoj=xournal.desktop;`
   to ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

3) added the MIME type `application/x-xoj` in the *File Associations* System Setting
   (with appropriate content):
[image: file-associations-xoj]
   (Note also that `application/x-gzip` specifies only the .gz extension:
[image].)

4) copied `xournal.xml` to /usr/share/mime/application
   as suggested [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes)

5) `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`

6) restarted the computer

*edited to add:*
7) [right-click an .xoj file] --> Open With --> Other... --> [select 'Xournal'], tick 'Remember application association for this type of file' also has no effect.
*end of edit*

This is on Kubuntu 12.04.
So, what am I missing?

*Edited to add*
I have discovered that the `file --mime-type [filename]` and `mimetype [filename]` commands produce different results, as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279899/file-mime-type-and-mimetype-commands-returning-different-results):

```
archelon@ingelrayok:~/Documents/xournal$ file --mime-type 2014-02-22-Note-02-09.xoj  
2014-02-22-Note-02-09.xoj: application/x-gzip  
archelon@ingelrayok:~/Documents/xournal$ mimetype 2014-02-22-Note-02-09.xoj  
2014-02-22-Note-02-09.xoj: application/x-xoj
```

However, there is no entry for `application/x-gzip` in /etc/mime.types (from which the `file` command supposedly gets its information); and, indeed, there shouldn't be, according to the comment at the beginning of that file, which reads in part:

> Note: Compression schemes like "gzip", "bzip", and "compress" are not
>    actually "mime-types".  They are "encodings" and hence must *not* have
>    entries in this file to map their extensions.  The "mime-type" of an
>    encoded file refers to the type of data that has been encoded, not the
>    type of encoding.

That comment also says that

> Users can add their own types if they wish by creating a ".mime.types"
>    file in their home directory.  Definitions included there will take
>    precedence over those listed here.

There is at present no such file.  There are some files in my home directory (which I didn't create) that are apparently related to the output of the `mimetype` command; these include
`~/.local/share/mime/application/x-xoj.xml`,
`~/.local/share/mime/packages/application-x-xoj.xml`, and
`~/.local/share/mime/types` which contains only the text `application/x-xoj`.
In fact the directory ~/.local/share/mime/ and everything in it have the same timestamp (22:19 last night), and were thus presumably generated by the same process.

After looking at the manpages for [mimetype](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/mimetype.1p.html) and [file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/file.1.html), I decided to check the environment variables `$XDG_DATA_HOME` and `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`, which apparently are used by the former but not the latter.  But I didn't know how to report the value of an environment variable, so I tried `cat $XDG_DATA_HOME`, which *set* the value (to nothing) instead of reporting it.  *Edited to add:  Or so I thought at first; actually it was already unset, as we shall see.* The correct command is `echo $XDG_DATA_HOME`, as I learned from reading about environment variables [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).  So then I discovered that `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` was set to `/usr/share/default:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/`; the first of these doesn't exist.  I don't think that matters, but anyway I ran the commands

```
XDG_DATA_HOME=$HOME/.local/share
```

and

```
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
```

to accord with the [standard](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).  I doubt that any of this will make any difference, but I'm going to try another restart now (although I think those environment variables will be automatically reset anyway). *Next edit*: Yes, they were; in fact the variable `XDG_DATA_HOME` is now null again.

Anyway the bottom line seems to be that KDE is using the functionality that `file` is using, rather than that which `mimetype` is using.  If I understand things correctly, this means that it is using magic instead of MIME types.  I now suspect that magic is responsible for this whole issue.

*New edit*

So the `file` [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/file.1.html) seems to be saying that these are the baseline magic files:

> /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc  Default compiled list of magic.
>   /usr/share/misc/magic      Directory containing default magic files.

(I have these; /usr/share/misc/magic is a link to the empty folder /usr/share/file/magic and /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc is a link to the file /usr/share/file/magic.mgc -- the latter is a 2.1 MB file full of gobbledygook) and the following text:

> The information identifying these files

(i.e. "files [which] have a ``magic number'' stored in a particular place near the beginning of the file")

> is read from /etc/magic and the compiled magic file
>    /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc, or the files in the directory
>    /usr/share/misc/magic if the compiled file does not exist.  In addition,
>    if $HOME/.magic.mgc or $HOME/.magic exists, it will be used in preference
>    to the system magic files.

(I have confirmed this with `strace`, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/105658/192986).)  Neither $HOME/.magic.mgc nor $HOME/.magic exists on my system; but, since presumably xoj files contain precisely that gobbledygook which causes a file to be magically identified as `application/x-gzip`, it would do no good to create them (please correct me if I am wrong).

The solution I'm looking for, then, would be a way to have the MIME-type specification override magic for a given file extension; I thought I had seen something that looked like it might provide a hint as to how that might be accomplished, but I can't find it now.  Yet surely such a method exists.

Comment: Have you tried opening a context menu on a `xoj` file in Dolphin and selecting "Open with..." then checking "Remember application association..."?

Comment: Yes.  It doesn't work.  (The 'updating system configuration' window appears and then the file opens with Xournal; but after I close it everything is the same: I click the file and it opens with Ark.)

Comment: I cannot help you, but I would suggest asking on [KDE forum](http://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=17), as there are much more chances to find the answer

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but just a comment:

> tried `cat $XDG_DATA_HOME`, which set the value (to nothing) instead
>   of reporting it

`cat` will certainly not set the value of the variable. `cat` would print the contents of the file of the name you provide it with, or in the absence of a file name it would print what it reads from standard input. Furthermore the variables are expanded by the shell you are running (usually `/bin/bash`) and thus `cat` doesn't even ever see the name of the variable.

Now in your specific situation, the variable seemingly wasn't set, thus expanded to nothing, thus `cat` had no parameter, thus `cat` printed from stdin and I presume you had to `Ctrl-C`-end it, or maybe `Ctrl-D` (end of file).

Comment: "So I had to uninstall the ppa version of Xournal and build from source (with a modification). And now .xoj files open automatically with KDE's archive manager Ark" Maybe you could try analysing what files the ppa version installs and how it makes it work correctly?

Comment: "I presume you had to Ctrl-C-end it": Yes. "try analysing what files the ppa version installs and how it makes it work correctly": I imagine I will end up trying to do just that.